# boton desplegable con autenticacion de usuario no despliega con laravel, bootstrap y html

Tags: html, css, laravel

Necesito realizar un inicio de sesion, el cual ya hice. Al momento de hacer responsivo el `nav bar` donde tengo algunos items, quiero que cuando el usuario inicie sesión muestre el nombre del usuario y que este despliegue la opción de cerrar sesión y que al momento de que no se encuentre loggeado solo aparezca el botón iniciar sesión. Ya lo tengo todo montado pero al momento de ponerlo en el `nav`, el desplegable de cerrar sesión no funciona de ninguna forma, lo he intentado solucionar de varias formas, pero al hacerlo este se desaparece del `nav bar`. Ya no se que mas hacer. iNecesito su ayuda y conocimiento!.

> Uso HTML, Bootstrap con CSS y Laravel.

Dejo el código completo del `nav bar` para que le echen un vistazo:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top shadow-sm" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container px-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold" href="#page-top">
      <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Texto alternativo de la imagen" width="200" height="80">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive"
      aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <strong>Menu</strong>
      <i class="bi-list"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-4 my-3 my-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3" href=""><strong>Inicio</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3" href=""><strong>Oversize</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3" href=""><strong>Zapatos</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3" href=""><strong>Pines</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3" href=""><strong>Marcas</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link me-lg-3" href=""><strong>Outlet</strong></a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto btn btn-primary rounded-pill px-3 mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <!-- Authentication Links -->
        @guest
        @if (Route::has('login'))
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link bi bi-person-circle me-2 color-white" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
        </li>
        @endif

        @if (Route::has('register'))
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link bi bi-box-arrow-up-right me-2 color-white" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register')
            }}</a>
        </li>
        @endif
        @else
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
          <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bi bi-person-circle me-2 text-white" href="#"
            role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
            {{ Auth::user()->name }}
          </a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item bi bi-door-open me-2 color-white" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
              {{ __('Logout') }}
            </a>

            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
              class="d-none bi bi-door-open me-2 color-white">
              @csrf
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
        @endguest
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Lo he intentado todo he incluso e cambiando de Bootstrap 5 al 4 y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Acomodé algunas cosas que se veían raro en tu pregunta. No soy experto en laravel así que espero que consigas respuesta.

Comment: @DABL03 tus modificaciones son buenas, y las aceptaría pero tengo un detalle. Si el código no es ejecutable dentro del fiddle, no lo agregues ahi. El fragmento está diseñado para que se pueda ejecutar javascript, html y css, además de mostrar el resultado. Al ser esto laravel (PHP), requiere de un servidor como tal para ejecutarse. Mejora tu edición, quitando el código hacia afuera, y quedará mejor visualmente.

Comment: hola, a todos he logrado corregir el codigo y ya funciona a la perfeccion, muchisimas gracias a los que aportaron con su comentario

Comment: @DavidSanchez, si has encontrado la solución, te invito a escribir una respuesta detallando la solución encontrada. Esto, para que si alguien tiene el mismo error que tú, se fije en ello y pueda solucionarlo 